# AngularJS - removing the line between SPA and AJAX data binding

Tags: ajax, angularjs

In Angular, speed is the name of the game and rendering views with useful data as quickly as possible is always sought after.  Angular allows us to reference data between the Controller and the View seamlessly using Angular's templating engine, which can make rendering views with  correctly bound data lightning fast.

For example, lets say we have a simple Angular App which is simply a table of contacts with fields like First Name, Last Name, Phone, Email, and Address.  We then want a Details view that appears when you click on a table row. We can wire up the `<tr>` to change views on click like this

`<tr ng-repeat="contact in Contacts" ng-click="showDetails(contact)">`

Then we can change the view and "instantly" show `contact` data in the new view. For example, we can change an `<h1>` at the top of the page to be **Contact - John Smith** using the data that was provided in `showDetails`.

While this data is being shown, more data can be retrieved from the server asynchronously that will then fill in the rest of the fields.

However, what do we do if we want to get to this details page directly from the url?  If the `contact` table was sitting at `/contacts` and the details page was something like `/contacts/detail/1` then attempting to go directly to `/contacts/detail/1` would result in the `<h1>` above to be blank.

This is clearly because we did not use the `showDetails()` method to invoke the view and pass the clicked `contact` into it directly.  In this case, we would need to take the contact id in the URL and run an AJAX request to get ALL of the data.

My question is, at what point do we draw the line between trying to make our views and data quickly accessible and making them robust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Robust is a must.

So we need to start there. Then we can move forward to optimize and make data "quickly accessible", as you put it, as much as possible.

In order to do that, every view in an SPA that is directly correlated to a URL needs to be initially stateless. That basically means that a reload on any url will load the desired view correctly and completely.

We can get the best of both worlds by using nested routes. If every route loads only what it needs, but also draws on parent routes (loading them if necessary, or just using them if they have already been provided) then you can achieve both robustness and "quick accessibility" to data.

In your particular example, the base route would be `contacts`. Then there could be a nested route inside of that which would display the details of a particular contact, `contacts/detail/{id}`. Loading the base url would load the list of contacts, and loading the details view would load both the list of contacts and the details of a particular contact. To provide quickly accessible data when going to the nested view, we could include logic that checks to see if the parent view data is already loaded, and only load if necessary. Then when navigating from the `contacts` to the `contacts/detail/{id}` view, we could quickly display data from the parent view in the child view, while loading data specific to the child view. A reload at `contacts/detail/{id}` would simply load both. When navigating back to the parent, the parent data would already be loaded.

Comment: So I am using `ui-router` already and have many nested views to create my application. What you say makes sense, I just don't understand how you can make the "parent" states load their information prior to the children states.  If you navigate to `contacts/detail/3` then you have no information about the `contact` with `id = 3` until you make a request to the server to get that info.

Comment: the child state needs access to data from the parent state. If the parent state has a list of contacts then you simply need to enumerate the contacts to find the right one and use that information. In `ui-router`, child views inherit resolves from parent states. So you can just pass a parent resolve into the child view's controller, and then retrieve the necessary ("quick") data from it it as described.

Comment: But it would still require an API call in the resolve to get the initial list. The original `contacts` list is created from an API

Comment: if you go to `contacts` view, contacts are loaded via API call from `contacts` resolve. then if you go to `contacts/detail/3` view, the quick info can be shown from the `contacts` resolve data while the details load via API call from `contacts/detail/3` controller. navigating directly to `contacts/detail/3` view requires the `contacts` resolves and view to be loaded first (because it's nested), and then the quick info can be shown from the `contacts` resolve data while the details load via API call from `contacts/detail/3` controller, just the same.

Comment: Oh, ok well that makes sense for that example.. However I don't think I can use that because my real application is architected differently.  The "List" of data is a sibling view with the "Details" because I couldn't have the details just be a child of the list, therefore the "List" controller is not invoked when going to the details view

Comment: If they are sibling views then just make a base view for both sibling views that loads the `contacts` data.

Comment: Perfect! That is what I did

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use something like `ui-router` to create complex routes, then you would not use `showDetails()` to alter the model, you would use `showDetails()` to alter the route. Then your model would set itself up based on the route, and your view would follow.

For example, you could have something like:

```
$scope.showDetails = function(contact) {
    $state.go('contacts.detail', { contactId: contact.id });
};
```

Then the controller could use `$stateParams` to retrieve any data you wanted for the specific contact from the server (asynchronously using promises). You could also include your own flavour of caching/loading via services to manage things like performance if you found it necessary.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your comment at all.

Comment: In the question, he asked where we draw the line between making our views and data "quickly accessible" and making them robust. You talked about how to make a robust app but you didn't address the "quickly accessible" part.

Comment: I only touched on it, but I did. Use complex partial routing using `ui-router`, and create cache/loading services. These are large concepts that are very specific to each app.

Comment: I actually am using `ui-router`, but the `$stateParams` can only hold so much information, and that info shows up in the URL, therefore I never like to put anything but a GUID of some sort in the `$stateParams`

Comment: That's what I mean. Use `$stateParams` like a GUID to talk to services to initialise the view.